# Conditionally exit out of a FOR loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, nested-loops

Cant seem to figure this one out - hope someone can provide advice

I have a batch file that has an array of servers and loops through these to stop then start a Windows service

The stop part is working fine and the array of server names and service etc is all working as expected - so I will skip that for now.

The start part is what is causing me problems

What I want to happen is:

- Try to start each server's service via a for loop (I can get this working OK)
- If it fails to start try 'x' more times then move onto the next server - I am trying to use a nested for loop (I think correct terminology) for this. It sort of works - but I want it to try to start the service - then check if running - if it is - break out of loop and go to next server in array - if it fails to start the service try 'x' more times then move on... I can't really seem to make this part work properly.

This is the code at present that sort of works but won't jump out of the nested loop if the service actually is started successfully. I have commented out the errorlevel check that I was trying to use to make it exit the loop if the service check did not error

```
rem Start service
echo 3. Starting "%service1%" Services >> %LOGPath%
for /L %%n in (0,1,1) do (

    echo Starting the "%service1%" service on !server[%%n]! >> %LOGPath%
    sc \\!server[%%n]! start "%service1%" > NUL
    
    rem Wait a specified time between each check
    timeout /t %StartWaitLoopDelay% /nobreak
    
    echo Service "%service1%" status on !server[%%n]! is: >> %LOGPath%
    sc \\!server[%%n]! query "%service1%" | find /I "STATE" | find "RUNNING" >> %LOGPath%
    if errorlevel 1 (
    
        for /L %%a in (1,1,2) do (
        echo The "%service1%" service failed to start on !server[%%n]! - attmepting restart %%a times >> %LOGPath%
        
            sc \\!server[%%n]! start "%service1%" > NUL
            
            rem Wait a specified time between each check
            timeout /t %StartWaitLoopDelay% /nobreak
            
            echo Service "%service1%" status on !server[%%n]! is now: >> %LOGPath%
            sc \\!server[%%n]! query "%service1%" | find /I "STATE" | find "RUNNING" >> %LOGPath%
            rem if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto ExitStartLoop
        )

    )
rem :ExitStartLoop
    
)
```

I have also tried the below using a Call (to another restart loop - then exit /b to try and get out of it) in the first loop if the service fails to start - also sort of works but not really - doesn't actually exit properly and prints the first loop code to output in cmd window...

```
rem Start service
echo 3. Starting "%service1%" Services >> %LOGPath%
for /L %%n in (0,1,1) do (

    echo Starting the "%service1%" service on !server[%%n]! >> %LOGPath%
    sc \\!server[%%n]! start "%service1%" > NUL
    
    rem Wait a specified time between each check
    timeout /t %StartWaitLoopDelay% /nobreak
    
    echo Service "%service1%" status on !server[%%n]! is: >> %LOGPath%
    sc \\!server[%%n]! query "%service1%" | find /I "STATE" | find "RUNNING" >> %LOGPath%
    if errorlevel 1 Call :RestartLoop 
    )
GoTo :End

:RestartLoop

        for /L %%a in (1,1,2) do (
        echo The "%service1%" service failed to start on !server[%%n]! - attmepting to restart %%a times >> %LOGPath%
        
            sc \\!server[%%n]! start "%service1%" > NUL
            
            rem Wait a specified time between each check
            timeout /t %StartWaitLoopDelay% /nobreak
            
            echo Service "%service1%" status on !server[%%n]! is now: >> %LOGPath%
            sc \\!server[%%n]! query "%service1%" | find /I "STATE" | find "RUNNING" >> %LOGPath%
            if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (exit /b)
        )


:End
```

Hope this makes sense and someone can provide some advice. I know I am using errorlevel and %errorlevel% - will clean this up if/when I can get it working correctly

Comment: Beware of the [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947). This applies also to magic variables like `errorlevel`. The syntax `if errorlevel n` however works on the current `errorlevel`.

Comment: Agreed...do not change `If ErrorLevel 1` to `If %ErrorLevel% == 1`, or `If %ErrorLevel% Equ 1`; or even with delayed expansion enabled, `If !ErrorLevel! == 1`, or `If !ErrorLevel! Equ 1`, `. What you are using in that regard is better.

Comment: OK thanks for that - I do have enabledelayedexpansion set and the variables in the loop etc are incrementing correclty - I have also tried errorlevel in the nested loop / restart loop - but still no luck - I am just not sure how to exit out of that correctly back to the original for loop - if the service start is succefull after 'x' attemps.

Comment: `if %errorlevel% EQU 0` should read `if not ErrorLevel 1` in both of your scripts. Anyway, I don't understand why you do one attempt in advance and then retry in a loop up to two times, instead of just trying in a loop up to three times…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use this method. The new lines inserted by me have an uppercase REM comment before.

```
rem Start service
echo 3. Starting "%service1%" Services >> %LOGPath%
for /L %%n in (0,1,1) do (

    echo Starting the "%service1%" service on !server[%%n]! >> %LOGPath%
    sc \\!server[%%n]! start "%service1%" > NUL
    
    rem Wait a specified time between each check
    timeout /t %StartWaitLoopDelay% /nobreak
    
    REM Clear "error" flag
    set "anyError="
    
    echo Service "%service1%" status on !server[%%n]! is: >> %LOGPath%
    sc \\!server[%%n]! query "%service1%" | find /I "STATE" | find "RUNNING" >> %LOGPath%

    REM If was an error, set "error" flag
    if errorlevel 1 set "anyError=true"

    for /L %%a in (1,1,2) do if defined anyError (

        echo The "%service1%" service failed to start on !server[%%n]! - attmepting restart %%a times >> %LOGPath%
        sc \\!server[%%n]! start "%service1%" > NUL
            
        rem Wait a specified time between each check
        timeout /t %StartWaitLoopDelay% /nobreak
            
        echo Service "%service1%" status on !server[%%n]! is now: >> %LOGPath%
        sc \\!server[%%n]! query "%service1%" | find /I "STATE" | find "RUNNING" >> %LOGPath%

        REM If was not an error, clear "error" flag
        if not errorlevel 1 set "anyError="

    )
    
)
```